# How to prefetch aggregated @property in Django?

Tags: django, orm, aggregate

We have two models (simplified versions):

```
class Contestant(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    # plus some other fields

    @property
    def total_points(self):
        return self.points.aggregate(total=Sum('value'))['total'] or 0

class Points(models.Model):
    contestant = models.ForeignKey(Contestant, related_name='points')
    value = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    # plus some other fields which determine based on what we
    # awarded ``Points.value``
```

When we display a list of contestants along with their `total_points` value, it
results in an extra query for each result - i.e. the following queries are performed:

1. fetch list of contestants
2. fetch `total_points` value of 1st contestant
3. fetch `total_points` value of 2nd contestant
4. etc

I tried altering the queryset to prefetch the data as follows:

```
Contestant.objects.filter(...).prefetch_related('points')
```

..., however even though it works, the prefetched data is not utilized when
listing contestants (so each result still tries to fetch `total_points`
in a separate query).

Is it possible to:

- somehow tell the ORM to use prefetched values for the @property field when
  populating data for individual model objects (e.g. access the prefetched value inside the `Contestant.total_points` @property method)?
- or to prefetch them in a different way (as opposed to the example above)?
- or to use a completely different approach achieving the same result?

(I'm listing results in `tastypie`, if it matters.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When your aim is to add aggregated values to each item, you should use [`annotate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset), instead of `aggregate`.

For example (a simple query, no additional methods required):

```
Contestant.objects.filter(...).annotate(total_points=Sum('points__value'))
```

---

If you really want to put this code out of your query: you can, but a model method is not a right way to do this. Methods on models are for operations on single instances. If you want to do something on a whole QuerySet use an [ORM Manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/) instead.

With a Manager this would look like this:

```
class TotalPointsManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(TotalPointsManager, self).get_queryset().annotate(total_points=Sum('points__value'))

class Contestant(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)

    objects = TotalPointsManager() # You are overriding the default manager!
```

and then you would construct your query as usual (you can drop `prefetch_related`):

```
Contestant.objects.filter(...)
```

...and `total_points` field would become "magically" available for every object.

Comment: +1. Thank you, I was thinking roughly along those lines as well. I need to check if we really need it everywhere. Let's wait if anyone suggest any alternatives, but this seems to be the most sensible approach I'm aware of as of now.

Comment: Note that we used https://github.com/initcrash/django-denorm in the end (for performance reasons), but I'm accepting this as it's a valid approach. Thanks, mate!

Comment: Awesome, this works but only using *get_query_set* instead of *get_queryset*

Comment: @JasonSack the name changed in Django 1.6. You probably use Django 1.5 or earlier.