# Django Rest Order on custom field from serializer?

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to use Django Rest to return a json representation of a model based on a ordering from a custom field that is not attached to the model, but is attached to the serializer. I know how to do this with model specific fields, but how do you use django rest to return an ordering when the field is only within the serializer class? I want to return a list of Pics ordered by 'score'. Thanks!

------Views.py

```
class PicList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Pic.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PicSerializerBasic
    filter_backends = (filters.OrderingFilter,)
    ordering = ('score')
```

------Serializer.py

```
class PicSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    userprofile = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    score = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Pic
        fields = ('title', 'description', 'image', 'userprofile', 'score')
        order_by = (('title',))

    def get_score(self, obj):
        return Rating.objects.filter(picc=obj).aggregate(Avg('score'))['score__avg']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could move the logic of the method `get_score` to the manager of the `class Pic`. [In this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19117814/2230003) there is an example of how to do it.

Once you have it in the manager, the `score` field would become "magically" available for every object of the `class Pic` everywhere (serializer, views...) and you'll be able to use it for ordering.