# How to add order_by to the custom serializer field in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

**Serializer:**

```
class RequestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    travel_date = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='get_traveldate')
    guests = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='get_num_of_guests')
    cost = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='get_invoice_cost')
    status = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='get_request_status')

    class Meta:
        model = Request
        fields = (guests, cost,)


class BookingView(generics.ListApiView):

     serializer_class = RequestSerializer
     model = serializer_class.Meta.model
     paginate_by = 15
     filter_fields = ('costs', 'guests')

     def get_queryset(self):
        req_dict = self.request.query_params
        client = int(req_dict.get('client'))
        start_date = date(int(req_dict.get('from_year')), int(req_dict.get('from_month')), 1)
        end_date = get_end_date(int(req_dict.get('to_year')),  int(req_dict.get('to_month')))
        requests = Request.objects.filter(guests__company__id=client, check_in__gte=start_date,
                                          check_out__lte=end_date)

        return requests
```

Answer (score 0):

You could move the logic of the **MethodField**s to the **manager** of the class **Request**.

Once you have it in the manager, they would become available for every object (serializer, views...) and you'll be able to use it for ordering.

[This is link will be helpful to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19117256/how-to-prefetch-aggregated-property-in-django/19117814#19117814)